# Add message to a definite place

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have on form `<p:messages>` and many `<p:message>` in most fields in tooltip:

```
<p:messages binding="#{myBean.messagesUI}" id="seria" closable="true" showDetail="true" globalOnly="false"/>    <h:outputText/>                                             
            <h:outputText value="S:" styleClass="r1" />
            <p:inputMask  id ="iSeria" value="#{varCardHolder.seria}" required="true" requiredMessage="Error" mask="9999" styleClass="r1">
            <p:tooltip for="iSeria">                            
                            <p:message for="iSeria" />
                    </p:tooltip>
            </p:inputMask>            
            <h:outputText value="N:" styleClass="r1" />
            <p:inputMask  id = "iNomer" value="#{varCardHolder.pasNumber}" required="true" requiredMessage="errrror" mask="999999" styleClass="r1">
                <p:tooltip for="iNomer">                            
                            <p:message for="iNomer" />
                    </p:tooltip>
            </p:inputMask>
```

When they fail validation, messages appear in toolotips and in `<p:messages>` too. I don't want them there. How to show validation messages only in tooltips `<p:message>` without using 
`globalOnly="true"` tag in `<p:messages>`?

Comment: Any specific reason for not using `globalOnly="true"` ??

Comment: yes. I have a rather comlicated structure of the view, and global messages are already used in other cases.